# The Code is not working in jupyter and giving the error as pictured below

Tags: python, jupyter, pymysql

Please help me to run this code on jupyter and see how the output will appear.

```
import pymysql 
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb() 
import MySQLdb  

db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "techgeeks")   

cursor= db.cursor() 
  

size_of_table = cursor.execute("""select table_name as "Table",
                               round(((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024),2)                               
                               as "Size(MB)"from information_schema.TABLES 
                               where table_schema="techgeeks" and 
                               table_name="geekcompanies" order by
                               (data_length+index_length)desc""") 
  

print(size_of_table)
```

[image]